# クラスのリストをインスタンス変数に持つクラスのソートがしたい

Tags: python, python3, sort

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, age, name):
       self.__age=age
       self.__name=name
   ...
   def record(self):
       return {'age':age,'name':name}

class Alist:
   def __init__(self, A):
       self.__a_list = [A]

   # あたらしくクラスAを代入する処理が続く
```

のような Python3.5 のコードがあるとして
Alistクラスを他のクラスを使って、Aの特定のキーでソートしたい時どのように実装すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: Alistクラスのインスタンス変数 __a_list　(Aクラスのオブジェクトのリスト)　を、Aクラスのインスタンス変数(age もしくは name)の値に基づいてソートしたい、という事でしょうか？　『 # あたらしくクラスAを代入する処理が続く』というのは、__a_listにAクラスのオブジェクトを追加するメソッドが有るという理解で良いでしょうか？　質問の内容を明確にするために確認させてください。

Comment: >Alistクラスのインスタンス変数 __a_list　(Aクラスのオブジェクトのリスト)　を、Aクラスのインスタンス変数(age もしくは name)の値に基づいてソートしたい、という事でしょうか？
そのとおりです。
>『 # あたらしくクラスAを代入する処理が続く』というのは、__a_listにAクラスのオブジェクトを追加するメソッドが有るという理解で良いでしょうか？
こちらもそのとおりです。
補足しますと、追加する際にユニークな値であることを確認する処理を加えますので、インスタンスが保持する情報に重複はないものと考えていただいて構いません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんなんどうでしょうか。

[sorted関数](https://docs.python.jp/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto)で検索対象とするキーを関数で指定できるようです。
それを利用して、Alist に sort_by_age, sort_by_name メソッドを追加してみました。

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, age, name):
      self.__age=age
      self.__name=name

   def record(self):
       return {'age':age,'name':name}

   # 内部変数をアクセス可能に
   @property
   def age(self):
      return self.__age

   @property
   def name(self):
      return self.__name

   # printしたときに見やすいように
   def __repr__(self):
      return "<A age:%d,name:%s>" % (self.__age, self.__name)


class Alist:
   def __init__(self, obj):
       self.__a_list = [obj]

   def add(self, obj):
      self.__a_list.append(obj)

   # 年齢でソートした配列を返却
   def sort_by_age(self):
      return sorted(self.__a_list, key=lambda a: a.age)

   # 名前でソートした配列を返却
   def sort_by_name(self):
      return sorted(self.__a_list, key=lambda a: a.name)
```

利用例は以下になります。

```
a1 = A(2, 'b_san')
a2 = A(1, 'c_san')
a3 = A(3, 'a_san')

alist = Alist(a1)
alist.add(a2)
alist.add(a3)

print(alist.sort_by_age()) #=> [<A age:1,name:c_san>, <A age:2,name:b_san>, <A age:3,name:a_san>]
print(alist.sort_by_name()) #=> [<A age:3,name:a_san>, <A age:2,name:b_san>, <A age:1,name:c_san>]
```

Comment: お二方にご教授頂いた方法で希望の動作を確認しました。
tanalab2様に頂いた解法が「今後インスタンス変数が増えても対応の負担が小さい」と判断したので、こちらをベストアンサーにしました。

Answer (score 1):

整数のリストのソートであれば、整数同士を大小比較しますよね。
質問は、「オブジェクトのリストのソートで、オブジェクトのインスタンス変数の値でソートしたい」という事ですから、整数同士の大小比較をしていた部分を、インスタンス変数の値の大小比較にすれば良いわけです。

バブルソートのコード(ネット上から拝借)の大小比較の部分『if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:』を

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
change = True
while change:
    change = False
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
            arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
            change = True
return arr
```

を『if arr[i].age > arr[i + 1].age:』に変更すれば、Aクラスのインスタンス変数ageでソートされるようになります。

テスト用データを作って、ageおよびnameでソートするコードを書いてみました。

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age=age
        self.name=name

#クラスAのインスタンス変数ageでソートしたリストを返す関数
def bubble_sort_age(arr):
    change = True
    while change:
        change = False
        for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[i].age > arr[i + 1].age:
                arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
                change = True
    return arr

#クラスAのインスタンス変数ageでソートしたリストを返す関数
def bubble_sort_name(arr):
    change = True
    while change:
        change = False
        for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[i].name > arr[i + 1].name:
                arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
                change = True
    return arr

#クラスAのリストを表示する関数
def print_listOfA(arr):
    print("No. \t Age \t Name")
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(i+1, "\t",arr[i].age, "\t",arr[i].name)
    print()


#List of class A objects
list=[]

#Sample data (ageでソートしてみる対象）
list += [A(18,"Yamamoto")]
list += [A(23,"Tanaka")]
list += [A(56,"Minami")]
list += [A(32,"Akiyama")]
list += [A(43,"Sato")]
list += [A(12,"Suzuki")]

print("ソート前のリスト")
print_listOfA(list)

#ageでソート（バブルソート)
list_ageOrder = bubble_sort_age(list)
print("ageでソート後のリスト")
print_listOfA(list_ageOrder)

#nameでソート（バブルソート)
print("nameでソート後のリスト")
list_nameOrder = bubble_sort_name(list)
print_listOfA(list_nameOrder)
```

実行結果:

> ソート前のリスト
>   No.      Age     Name
>   1        18      Yamamoto
>   2        23      Tanaka
>   3        56      Minami
>   4        32      Akiyama
>   5        43      Sato
>   6        12      Suzuki 
>   ageでソート後のリスト
>   No.      Age     Name
>   1        12      Suzuki
>   2        18      Yamamoto
>   3        23      Tanaka
>   4        32      Akiyama
>   5        43      Sato
>   6        56      Minami 
>   nameでソート後のリスト
>   No.      Age     Name
>   1        32      Akiyama
>   2        56      Minami
>   3        43      Sato
>   4        12      Suzuki
>   5        23      Tanaka
>   6        18      Yamamoto